# Does the sandbox enviroment still work once the iphone app goes live?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, sandbox

Does the sandbox environment still work once the app goes live ?

I just want to know if i will be able to further test my in-app purchase once the app is approved by apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you use your developer certificate to sign your app and sign in to iTunes using the account you created in iTunes Connect, the sandbox is still present and usable.